# Couldn't find exit status "test -e ... " on Solaris based remote server

Tags: emacs, elisp, tramp

When opening some files on a remote Solaris server through emacs-tramp I get this error:
Couldn't find exit status "test -e 'file path'..."
And then the file opens as "Fundamental" without figuring out the type (C++/C/verilog...etc) so no fontification...etc

Any reason for this or a solution?

Comment: I have the problem when I open a remote-file first. If I call `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` and reopen the same remote-file, it works.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue a long time ago, but was never able to figure out what happens. Basically, the error message means that the *binary* `test` cannot be executed (i.e. it's not using the shell built-in). You need to add the path to the `test` binary, in my case this was `/usr/bin/`, so I ended up putting the following bit into my `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/usr/bin")
```

On my Windows-based Emacs 24.1, though `tramp-remote-path` has a default with  `tramp-default-remote-path` which includes `/usr/bin` already.

Comment: I added the path but still did not work.
My test binary was in /bin

Comment: `tramp-remote-path` is a buffer-local variable. Can you check the value of `tramp-remote-path` in the buffer (that hopefully gets created)?

Comment: It worked with me trying "tramp-cleanup-connection" on ubuntu